# rewrite rule explantion required

Tags: mod-rewrite

RewriteRule (.*) index.php

Can you explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule matches requests to all possible URL paths and rewrites them to *index.php*.

Comment: Hi Gumbo. Thanks for the answer. Can you also tell me what is this?

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]

Comment: @Vivek Chandraprakash: The *E* flag sets an environment variable. In this case the value of the HTTP header field *Authorization* is assigned to the environment variable *HTTP\_AUTHORIZATION*.

Answer (score 0):

This points any web address given to index.php. The first argument is a regular expression (look it up if you don't know) and the second is of course the page to redirect to. Note that the redirect is on the server side and so isn't visible to the outside user, and this is therefore how websites make their addresses easier to read.

Comment: thanks. can you tell me what this means?

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]

Comment: This will explain it: http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/http-auth-php-cgi.html

Answer (score 0):

The very first result on google for "RewriteRule" is [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule).  It very clearly explains the syntax.

`(.*)` is a regular expression which matches all incoming requests.  It's basically saying any request that comes in, behave as if the user requested `index.php`

Comment: thanks for the reply. can you tell me what thsi means?             

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]